# Problema com Order By Case Com mais de 9 When

Tags: mysql, sql

Como usar corretamente o ORDER BY CASE WHEN com mais de 9 registros ?

No exemplo abaixo estou utilizando um case when com mais de 9 registros e quando chega na posição 10 , 11 ,12 e 13 a ordem fica errada.

Qual é a maneira correta de utilizar neste caso ?

```
ORDER BY CASE descricao
WHEN 'Rec. Op. Liquida' THEN 0
WHEN 'VENDA MERCADORIA' THEN 1
WHEN 'ICMS S.T S/ VENDA' THEN 2
WHEN 'DEVOLUÇÃO DE VENDA' THEN 3
WHEN 'VENDA LÍQUIDA' THEN 4
WHEN 'ICMS' THEN 5
WHEN 'ICMS ST' THEN 6
WHEN 'TOTAL ICMS' THEN 7
WHEN 'PIS' THEN 8
WHEN 'COFINS' THEN 9
WHEN 'TOTAL PIS/COFINS' THEN 10
WHEN 'DEV X FAT' THEN 11
WHEN 'BONF X FAT' THEN 12
WHEN 'BONIFICAÇÃO' THEN 13
ELSE descricao END;
```

Nesta imagem esta o resultado e do lado a posição do elemento no resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Exemplo no SQLFiddle [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d79ea/1), não consegui fazer rodar direito
>   por que uso muitas variaveis e multiplas querys, se alguem puder
>    ajustar para o exemplo ficar melhor agradeço, mas o resultado pode ser visto na imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou utilizando desta forma, usei dois caracteres e botei aspas

```
ORDER BY CASE descricao
WHEN 'Rec. Op. Liquida' THEN '01'
WHEN 'VENDA MERCADORIA' THEN '02'
WHEN 'ICMS S.T S/ VENDA' THEN '03'
WHEN 'DEVOLUÇÃO DE VENDA' THEN '04'
WHEN 'VENDA LÍQUIDA' THEN '05'
WHEN 'ICMS' THEN '06'
WHEN 'ICMS ST' THEN '07'
WHEN 'TOTAL ICMS' THEN '08'
WHEN 'PIS' THEN '09'
WHEN 'COFINS' THEN '10'
WHEN 'TOTAL PIS/COFINS' THEN '11'
WHEN 'DEV X FAT' THEN '12'
WHEN 'BONF X FAT' THEN '13'
WHEN 'BONIFICAÇÃO' THEN '14'
ELSE descricao END;
```